# Cocoa -- toggling a BOOL without repeating its name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, boolean

If a BOOL has a nice short name, it's easy enough to write:

```
myBOOL = !myBOOL;
```

But what if the BOOL has a long name?

```
objectWithLongishName.memberWithLongishName.submember.myBOOL = !(objectWithLongishName.memberWithLongishName.submember.myBOOL);
```

. . . does not look so pretty.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to toggle the BOOL without entering its name twice?

Comment: Just curious, can you multiply a `bool` by a numeric in Objective-C? Could you do soemthing like `objectWithLongishName.memberWithLongishName.submember.myBOOL*=-1;`? It seems like that would be a very *very* bad way to do it, but I'm just wondering now if it would work...

Comment: @frust: Other issues aside, how would that work arithmetically? `0 * -1 = 0`.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: hahaha! Ok, good point. I thought I'd seen that trick *some* where, but I can't remember where (though I know it wasn't Objective-C).

Comment: You could conceivably do `myBool ^= 1`…but I wouldn't.

Comment: @Wevah: maybe that's what I was thinking of...?

Comment: @William: you should really specify a platform. BOOL datatype and YES/NO constants are not a part of Objective C proper, they're defined in the Cocoa headers. Objective C, like C, has no boolean datatype.

Comment: Wevah -- that is awesome.  I would do that, absolutely . . . want to make it an answer?  If you don't, I will.

Comment: Oh…I should have. Looks like I was beaten to the punch—twice—though. :/

Comment: Seva Alekseyev: Both of those statements are untrue. `BOOL`, `YES`, and `NO` are defined in `<objc/objc.h>`, and C, as of C99, does have a Boolean type: `_Bool` (§6.2.5), with a macro of `bool` defined in `<stdbool.h>` (§7.16). `true` and `false` are also defined in stdbool.h (§7.16). `_Bool` and `BOOL` aren't binary compatible, though: While C99 doesn't directly define the sign or size of `_Bool` (besides requiring that it be big enough to hold 0 and 1), §6.2.5¶6 includes it among the “standard unsigned integer types”; meanwhile, Objective-C's objc.h defines `BOOL` as a `signed char`.

Comment: @Peter: um, still a #define, still not a native datatype. A part of the standard ObjC RTL at best. And given the nature and the prominence of BOOL in Cocoa, the existence of C99 _Bool is utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another:

```
MyBooleanYaddaYadda ^= YES;
```

This is kinda brittle - it will break on legacy C code that implies that any nonzero integer evaluates to true. But then again, so will Apple framework code - I encountered cases in Cocoa where a nonzero, non-one int, when passed as a BOOL, would not cause the same effect as passing a YES.

However, it does not rely on the bit pattern of YES - only on NO being 0. Which is pretty much a given, considering the way C interprets integers as logical values. Also, it does not assume the actual datatype of BOOL (which on Cocoa is `signed char`, by the way).

The bit pattern of YES on Cocoa is 1. But that's not a universal convention. On some platforms with no built-in boolean datatype, the integer constant that serves as a logical TRUE is `-1` - all one bits. That's 0xFFFFFFFF if interpreted as unsigned. This coding has a vague advantage that bitwize NOT (the ~ operator in C ) is equivalent to logical NOT (the ! operator in C). That is, ~0xFFFFFFFF is 0, i. e. ~TRUE is FALSE. Doesn't work that way if TRUE is defined as 1.

Comment: It kind of fails from a code clarity point. At a casual glance, it looks like an assignment to YES. Use it a lot, and the idiom will likely stand out, but hit it fresh, it'll probably cause a bit of head scratching.

Comment: IMO the brevity and lack of required associated infrastructure (i.e. macro definitions) outweigh this disadvantage.  That's why I accepted this answer.  To each his own, though.

Answer (score 10):

```
#define NOT(b) (b) = !(b)

NOT(MyBooleanVariableWithAFreakishlyLongName);
```

Or, if it's Objective C++:

```
inline void NOT(BOOL &b)
{
    b = !b;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

No there isn't an obvious way in (Objective-)C to do what you describe (without using a preprocessor macro), but see Seva's answer for a possible (though potentially brittle) solution. More importantly, something like `objectWithLongishName.memberWithLongishName.submember.myBOOL` indicates a [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violation; you should be providing `submember` directly to any code unit that needs to access `submember.myBOOL`.

Comment: Why is aBool ^= YES unfeasible?

Comment: @Kalle, good point. I think @Seva Alekseyev makes the point pretty clearly. Using `^=` is potentially brittle, but will work in many situations.

Answer (score 6):

Write a method for the `submember` class that toggles it for you?

```
- (void) toggleMyBOOL {
  self.myBool = !self.myBool;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
[objectWithLongishName.memberWithLongishName.submember toggleMyBOOL];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use XOR. In C, this is ^.

```
BOOL x = YES;
x ^= YES; // it's now NO
x ^= YES; // it's now YES
x ^= YES; // it's now NO
x ^= YES; // it's now YES
x ^= YES; // it's now NO
x ^= YES; // it's now YES
...
```

Edit: someone posted this already, apparently. I guess I should say I've never actually used this in code. :-)

Comment: Note that that's a bitwise XOR, which means that if `x` is, for some reason, set to any value other than 1 or 0, it will always remain true, since you're only flipping the lowest bit. Using `~NO` will replace that problem with another: You'll be flipping *all* the bits, with the same result: `x` simply alternates between two true values.

Comment: And *that's* why I posted it as a comment and said "…but I wouldn't". ;) It sure is "neat" though.

Comment: If you manage to get a BOOL to equal a value other than 1 or 0 then yes, you'll have problems. But won't you, regardless?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lovely set of answers focused on flipping a YES to a NO or vice-versa, but <s>no answers</s> that touched on what would appear to be an architectural issue in the code.

Well, some answers.  I'm blind.

Namely, you have this:

```
objectWithLongishName.memberWithLongishName.submember.myBOOL =
    !(objectWithLongishName.memberWithLongishName.submember.myBOOL);
```

That smells like a potential encapsulation violation.  In particular (and assuming this is a model layer), it means that the connectivity of the sub-graph of objects is being overtly exposed -- flattened into, effectively -- the entry point of that path;  whatever `objectWithLongishName` is must now have rather intimate knowledge of the innards of the objects along the rest of the path.

Typically, you don't reach deeply into the model layer along key paths to edit state outside of the Cocoa Bindings layer (and even that is a bit fragile).

Sometimes such long-ish paths do make sense.  In such a case, I would leave the über-verbose form you have above as a visual indication that encapsulation is being purposefully shred.

Comment: @Barry Wark mentioned this (The violation of the Law of Demeter)

Comment: Actuall, the *first* (or one of the first) answer (Barry Wark's answer) mentioned that.