# What's the shortest way to negate a BOOL in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I remember in Java you could just go

```
bool yesNo = YES;
!yesNo;
```

and it would be NO automatically.  I've tried this a few times in Objective-C but it doesn't seem to work.  Is there a language specific way to do this in Objective-C?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313281/cocoa-toggling-a-bool-without-repeating-its-name/3313904#3313904

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works more or less the same way - you just have to remember to assign the result of the negation expression back to the variable, like so:

```
yesNo = !yesNo;
```

Comment: eh yeah that's what I ended up doing.